# Static variables and instance block in Java

Tags: java, static-variables

When initializing an instance variable in a static block, it's throwing compilation error (so only static variables are declared in static block). However, my program is executing without any problem when I'm initializing static variable in an instance initializer block. So, is it OK to initialize static variable in instance block?

Comment: you need to provide more information like the programming language that you are using and code examples

Comment: If it is okay or not depends on the use-case and what you want to do. There is no problem in accessing (and changing) static fields when working with instances.

Comment: In general, avoid either static or instance initializer blocks unless you *really* need them. It is better to initialize the member with an assignment (e.g. `private int yourField = 123;`, or in the constructor in the case of instance variables.

Comment: It's possible but pointless, You want to initialize them once, not per-instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to do this, but usually not desirable. The instance initializer block will run whenever a new instance is created, and overwrite any existing value in the static fields.